# PROLOG: Check if first list contains 3 times less of each element than second list

Tags: prolog

I need to check if each element in second list has 3 times more instances then the same element in the first list. My function returns false all the time and I don't know what I'm dong wrong.

Here is the code:

```
fourth(_,[ ]).
fourth(A,[HF|TF]) :-
    intersection(A, HF, NewA),
    intersection(TF, HF, NewB),
    append(HF, NewB, NewT),
    append(NewA, NewA, NewAA),
    append(NewA, NewAA, NewAAA),
    length(NewAAA) == length(NewT),
    select(HF, TF, NewTF),
    fourth(A, NewTF).
```

Example:

```
?- fourth([1,2,3], [1,1,1]).
true.

?- fourth([1,2,3], [1,1,1,1]).
false.

?- fourth([1,2,3], [1,1]).
false.

?- fourth([1,2,2,3], [1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2]).
true.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make myself a `select/3` predicate: `select(X,From,Left)`, and then for each elt of a first list I'd call it three times with same first argument on a second list, progressively passing it forward, getting me a final `Left3` without the three occurences of `X`; iand I'd do *that* for each elt of a first list. Then if I'd succeed and end up with an empty list, that means it had exactly three times each elt from the first list.

Comment: Note that if you use SWI-pl's **select/3**, it'd fail for fourth([1,2,3], [1,1,1]). while it shouldn't if you respect OP specification. Use of **member/2** before the use of **select/3** to know whether or not the current first list element is in the second list should handle the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems needlessly complicated. It also contains bugs where you use `HF` instead of the list `[HF]`.

So what's the logic you want to implement?:

1. take the next element from the second list (leaving the tail)
2. check if it's in the first list, and if it is, remove it (else fail)
3. remove it two more times from the tail of the second list

and this gives:

```
fourth(_,[ ]).
fourth(A,[HF|TF]) :-
     once(select(HF, A, AR)), % using once/1 to avoid choicepoints
     once(select(HF, TF, TF1)),
     once(select(HF, TF1, TFR)),
     fourth(AR, TFR).
```

Comment: It's homework, maybe explicit code isn't welcome. And your answer follows what's already suggested by Will Ness.

Comment: Point taken. Though I always felt I learned more and faster from analyzing good solutions than struggling to come up with a mediocre one. Don't know how it's done these days, but I would ask for a thorough explanation of the reasoning, so just copying the code won't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with suggestions on why it fails :

```
fourth(_,[]).
fourth(A,[HF|TF]) :-
    intersection(A, HF, NewA),
    intersection(TF, HF, NewB),
```

It's not **intersection/3** that you want to use, for two reasons :

1) it doesn't filter only HF in A.

2) it fails if you call it with an element, so at least use [HF] instead
of HF

Instead, use **include/3** : include(=(HF), A, NewA). See SWI-pl doc for more info.

```
    append(HF, NewB, NewT),
    append(NewA, NewA, NewAA),
    append(NewA, NewAA, NewAAA),
```

Use of **append/2** is better, especially for your NewAAA list.

```
    length(NewAAA) == length(NewT),
```

You can't compare lengths like that. First, **length/1** doesn't exist in
built-in swi-pl predicates. Instead, compare directly the lists or use
**length/2** twice and then compare the results.

```
    select(HF, TF, NewTF),
    fourth(A, NewTF).
```

Only removing once HT in TF will cause your algorithm to fail. You need
to remove all the occurrences of HT in TF, with **subtract/3** for example...

If you want a working solution respecting your original work, I'll add it, so feel free to ask, but as it was tagged homework I'll let you those working leads first...

Answer (score 0):

% Blocks in our "block world"
%
%      b3
%      b4  b7
%  b1  b5  b8
%  b2  b6  b9
%==============

% Block Stacking
on(b1,b2).
on(b3,b4).
on(b4,b5).
on(b5,b6).
on(b7,b8).
on(b8,b9).

% Stack order
left(b2,b6).
left(b6,b9).

% Generalize "above"
above(Above,Below) :- on(Above,Below).
above(Above,Below) :- on(Above,AnyBlock), above(AnyBlock,Below).

% isLeft(X,Y) resolves to true if X is a block left of any block Y.
% isLeft/2 simply invokes leftOf/2 followed by a cut (!) to guarantee that
% only one result is generated.
%
% For Example:  isleft(b1,b7) produces true
%               isleft(b2,b6) produces true
%               isleft(b4,b5) produces false.
%               isleft(b9,b3) produces false.

isLeft(X,Y) :- leftOf(X,Y), !.
% Show an implementation of leftOf below. The implementation will involve a
% few cases (like the above predicate above), but can be completed using only the
% provided left and above predicates.